# how to set Orientation after launch on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

i Will like to know how to auto rotate iphone after launch.

my launch image is in portraits but the app itself are in landscape.

after launch the orientation are still in portraits instead of auto rotate to landscape.

this is my info.plist

[image]

in my root view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));

}
```

Comment: is only your launch screen in potrait and rest in landscape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

as shown in the image, set the marked value for landscape mode..

Comment: But my launch image is in portrait mode

Comment: ok then, after launch image is done run this step,

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

Comment: There's an [official guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW9) to launching an app in landscape

Answer (score 1):

In iphone Launch images are always in portrait mode, You can make launch image such that it looks like it is in landscape but actually it will be in portrait mode

While ipad has option for launch image in both mode landscape and portrait