# How to set default orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, device-orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set Orientation after launch on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060019/how-to-set-orientation-after-launch-on-iphone)

How would I go about setting the default orientation for the application, as in the orientation that the splash screen is in, and that the application is in before autorotating?

Comment: If you already answered it on your own, post the solution as an answer to help future visitors find solutions to similar problems.

Comment: PD: if you just want to Share your knowledge please follow this guideline http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ (No need for the self-answered thing, just answer your own question) When you make the question there is a tick box you can select that says "Answer Your Own Question"

Comment: @LuisOscar that's what I was trying to do... apparently I did it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following:

-Add "Initial Interface Orientation" key into info.plist.

-Change the value to the desired orientation (as a string; see "supported interface orientations" for the possible string values).

Answer (score -1):

In `-(void)shouldAutoRotateInterfaceOrientation` delegate, put like this if you want to have landscape as default:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

Comment: This is just wrong in so many ways...

Comment: Okay, first that method doesnt exist, and even if it did a void DOESNT return anything, if you mean - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation then the return type expects a boolean, so you CANT return THAT (Because it is an integer). Even if you return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
==YES). That would only LOCK that view to that orientation, which is not what the question is about.