# iOS SpriteKit node position

Tags: ios, position, sprite-kit, landscape-portrait

I an new at Sprite kit and I want to add some node to scene. 
My problem is positions :

If I put :

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Poligon"];
sprite.xScale = 0.5;
sprite.yScale = 0.5;
sprite.position = CGPointMake(40, 400);
```

it looks right when iPhone is in landscape mode, but when it is in portrait it disappear from the screen.

My guess is that it take coordinate from landscape and put it at right side of the screen. This would explain why node is not visible in portrait mode.

My question is how to set that iPhone would take portrait mode by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set Orientation after launch on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060019/how-to-set-orientation-after-launch-on-iphone)

Comment: No it is not :D My application launch in portrait mode, but coordinate system is set as it would be running landscape mode.

Comment: "My question is how to set that iPhone would take portrait mode by default?" that thread answers this question. I think you need to rephrase what you mean exactly.

Comment: You must read whole question not just last line :D I found question that help me in http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions

Comment: Your question details how you are having trouble with coordinates when the device is in landscape, then you ask how you can make it default to portrait. Can you understand why that is ambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently sprite kid start in landscape mode and take start viewDidLoad before it take rotation in account. Because of this the coordinate system in portrait mode is shifted, even if you set orientation to portrait.

[image]

The solution according to :

http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions

is to set your scene not on viewDidLoad but on

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

This is run after orientation is set and it works.